# Can I describe an apple as "Half of an apple, it is red"?

Tags: syntax, exam-questions, image-identification

Part of the TOEIC test is to describe pictures. So I’m picking random pictures and describing as many as possible. And my goal is to get a perfect score on TOEIC.

How can I describe this picture of an apple?

[image: A red apple cut in half]

It isn’t entirely red but partially green and yellow inside. So I can’t describe it as “(a) half of an apple is red.”

But in the exam I have to use the word “half”, so I can’t say, “**a part of** an apple is red.”

Then, what should I say? Is there no other way but to say

> “**Half of** an apple, it is red.”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A "red apple" does not mean the flesh is red, it means that the skin is red.

> This is half of a red apple.

When we describe an object by an adjective, we are describing what it is significant (this is how human language works, nothing special about English).  A red car has red paint on the outside. A pink grapefruit has pink juice (but a yellow skin).

For the sake of the TOEIC test, there are two points.  Firstly this is the wrong sort of picture to practice on. [TOIEC tests](https://www.englishclub.com/esl-exams/ets-toeic-practice-writing.htm) normally have pictures of people interacting in some context and secondly you need to give an extended description.

> This is half an apple. Two pips can be seen in the core of the apple. The skin of the apple is red, with small green spots, and the flesh of the apple is greenish-white. There aren't any toothmarks in the apple.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133301/discussion-on-answer-by-james-k-how-can-i-express-this-picture).